# Ruby gem for timeline from various social sites

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, social-networking

I want to create a ruby/rails application that displays a user's (my) updates from various social sites, e.g. facebook, linked-in, twitter, gmail, etc. in a timeline view.

Is there a gem that can help me achieve this easily, or do I need to be dependent on individual gems like koala, twitter, etc. for this purpose?

Can someone suggest me a better way to create such an application, as I would prefer not to utilize several social network's APIs due to `Lines-of-Code` and `performance` concerns. Is there a single API that provides such an interface?

Comment: a comment explaining the downvote definitely helps me understand my fault :)

Comment: someone thinks you requested an opinion. you did not - and people should not just downvote for no other reason than they can't answer a question. opinions are bad for forums like this one that tune for useful answers, but your question is "what library does X", which is not an opinion

Comment: We're probably headed for a "No" on this question. The reason is (despite commonalities like OAuth or RSS), every social media channel is different, and the industry has no incentive to do all the work required to merge them behind a common interface. ActiveMerchant, by contrast, HAS an incentive to merge all the payment gateways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched extensively for such a library, but at the moment, no such library exists.